# Zoomable panel in netbeans

Tags: java, swing

I have to create an application in Java, that allow the user to display a URL in a small panel, and it should allow the user to zoom the panel so as it covers the other components in the frame.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a LayeredPane and putting the component on top of the other components.  Here is the tutortial on how to use them: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

Answer (score 1):

[`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#card) might be a suitable choice.